# Concatenating A Cell To The One Above It And Deleting The Original

Tags: excel, vba

How would I make a VBA script that would run as follows:

If the first cell of the currently selected row is blank, concatenate the 2nd cell in the current row to the one above it and delete the current row while shifting the cells below up.

I had this as a formula in one of my cells but it turns out I need it to be a macro because I can't have a formula delete it's current row

```
=IF(AND(A8<>"",A9=""),CONCATENATE(B8," ",B9))
```

I'm completely lost as to where to start and any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the question is how to delete a row in excel-vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with these codes I guess. If you need a loop, you can insert a for loop an delete selection part.

```
Sub lalala()
Dim rowNum As Long
rowNum = Selection.Row

If Selection = "" And Cells(rowNum, 1) = "" Then

Cells(rowNum - 1, 2).Value = Cells(rowNum - 1, 2).Value & " " & Cells(rowNum, 2).Value
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you so very much- I'll fiddle with it to get it to run as a for loop but VBA has been giving me troubles since I'm used to Javascript.